# Django Admin - 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: django

When I try and delete records within Django Admin, for some records, I am getting

> 'bool' object is not callable

I cannot work out where the error is based on this Traceback.

```
Traceback:

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  575.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in delete_view
  1736.             return self._delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _delete_view
  1760.             [obj], opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in get_deleted_objects
  131.     collector.collect(objs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in collect
  195.             return super().collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)

File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/django-authenticjobs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in collect
  222.                         field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/jobboard/job/155/delete/
Exception Value: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Can anyone suggest where to look?  Thank you

Comment: Did you by any chance have set `on_delete=` on `True`/`False` instead of a `models.CASCADE`, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set an `on_delete` of a `ForeignKey`, or `OneToOneField` to a boolean (`True` or `False`). So something like:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_fk = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, on_delete=False)
```

You can not set this to a boolean. You can set this to the values listed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete): `CASCADE`, `PROTECT`, `SET_NULL`, `SET_DEFAULT`, `SET(..)`, or `DO_NOTHING`.

You could, strictly speaking, implement your own strategy as well, since the ones listed above are in fact just functions. For example the [`CASCADE` is implemented like [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/deletion.py#L14):

> ```
> def CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
>     collector.collect(sub_objs, source=field.remote_field.model,
>                       source_attr=field.name, nullable=field.null)
>     if field.null and not connections[using].features.can_defer_constraint_checks:
>         collector.add_field_update(field, None, sub_objs)
> ```

although likely you do not need to implement your own, and pick one of the ones listed in the documentation. For example:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_fk = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```